# Group and sum 2 columns in rails activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have this query:

```
Order.joins(cart: { cart_items: :product })
     .group("products.name", "cart_items.amount")
     .count
     .map { |a, b| { name: a[0], amount: a[1] * b} }
```

It returns something like this:

```
[{:name=>"Lorem", :amount=>1},
 {:name=>"Lorem", :amount=>2},
 {:name=>"Foo",   :amount=>1}]
```

The problem is because if I have 2 cart_items with the same product, it returns 2 values, as you can see in the product "Lorem"

I expect something like this:

```
[{:name=>"Lorem", :amount=>3},
 {:name=>"Foo",   :amount=>1}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want:

```
  Order.joins(cart: { cart_items: :product })
      .group("products.name")
      .select("products.name as product_name", "SUM(cart_items.amount) as cart_items_amount")
      .map { |order| { name: order.product_name, amount: order.cart_items_amount } }
```

Comment: unfortunately it returns results like [{:name=>"Lorem", :amount=>1}, {:name=>"Foo", :amount=>2}, {:name=>"Lorem", :amount=>2}] . I could easily agroup with some lines of code, but I think I can achive only with activerecord

Comment: Could you please try: ` Order.joins(cart: { cart_items: :product })
      .group("products.name")
      .select("products.name as product_name", "SUM(cart_items.amount) as cart_items_amount")
      .map { |order| { name: order.product_name, amount: order.cart_items_amount } }`
What's the output of this